# Find a username within instance wide objects

Tags: sql-server

A user's AD account keeps being locked out. The latest idea from colleagues is that their username and password is hard-coded in some database in the instance (a stored procedure for example).

1. Is this possible?
2. How would I search the instance for where this could be?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674872/4406684) on SO probably gives what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the text of a proc/function you could use the easy and free to use third party plugin of redgate:     [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/), there are also ways to do this with TSQL, see [answer on stackexchange searching through procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704105/search-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

However, very likely your proc will fetch the value from a table that stores it, so the proc doesn't have to be hard coded. 
If you want to search through a bunch of columns at the same time, this link might be useful to you:
[Finding string in different tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/)

Answer (score 0):

To generate a script that you could search through with all database objects/code: Right click on DB > Tasks > Generate Scripts > Next on Intro screen > On Choose objects screen tick 'Select specific database objects' and tick the objects you want to search > On Set Scripting Options Screen, select 'Save to new query window' > Summary Screen - click Next > click finish.

You can now do a Control + F to search through all of the scripts to find your username/password.

It is also possible to use this method to include the data values in the script, though this could be a huge script depending on the size of your database. To do this, on the 'Set Scripting Options' screen, click advanced > then change 'Types of data to script' to schema and data.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database are you running?

If it's an Oracle Database than you can do a SQL Query on dba_source/all_source and do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_source ds
WHERE ds.TEXT LIKE '%Username%'
```

For Microsoft Database you would do:

```
SELECT
    name,
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
FROM
    sys.procedures 
WHERE
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%Username%'
```

I had a query that would run through every schema/database on a server looking for this information, because what I was looking for might not be in my database, but I'll have to dig it up if you need more than the above.

The first query I remembered, the second I took from here: https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/search-find-stored-procedure

Good luck!!